# Save Matplotlib animation Tikzplotlib

Tags: python, tikz

I have a numerical simulation that I run with a short python code using animation.Funcanimation. Is is possible to use tikzplotlib to produce a .tex file including the whole simulation (and not just one picture) ? This would mean combining tikz and the animate package, for instance. For the moment my sole idea is to export each of the pictures and try to do so something directly with latex (but even this is not completely clear for me !).

Here is an example of short simulation :

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# Sites
M = 10
sites = np.array(range(M))

# Particles
N = 3

# Right hand side
def lotka(t,x):
    u = x[0:M]
    v = x[M:]
    dudt = u-u*u-u*v
    dvdt = v-u*v-v*v
    dxdt = np.concatenate((dudt,dvdt))
    return dxdt

# Initial conditions
u0 = np.zeros(M)
v0 = np.zeros(M)

# Segregated
u0[0] = N
v0[-1] = N
if M%2 == 0:
    for i in range(int(M/2)):
        u0[i] = N
        v0[M-1-i] = N
else:
    for i in range(int(np.floor(M/2))-1):
        u0[i] = N
        v0[M-1-i] = N

x0 = np.concatenate((u0,v0))

# Solving the equation
nt = 500
t = np.linspace(0,0.2,nt)
x = solve_ivp(lotka,[0,4],x0,t_eval=t)

# Getting each species from the solution of solve_ivp
u = np.zeros((nt,M))
v = np.zeros((nt,M))

for i in range(nt):
    u[i] = x.y.T[i][0:M]
    v[i] = x.y.T[i][M:]

# Animation
data = [u, v]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.grid()
lines = [ax.plot(sites,u[0])[0], ax.plot(sites,v[0])[0]]
time_template = 'time = % s'
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
lines.append(time_text)

def animate(i,lines,data):
    lines[0].set_ydata(data[0][i])
    lines[1].set_ydata(data[1][i])
    lines[2].set_text(time_template % t[i])
    return lines

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                               animate,
                               #frames=200,
                               fargs=(lines,data),
                               interval=1,
                               blit=True)

plt.show()
```